# Atomic find-and-delete in MongoDB using $isolated?

Tags: mongodb, atomic

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and I'm wondering if it's possible to be able to find and delete a number of documents atomically (the result needs to contain the documents). I'm trying to ensure that other application threads will never read these documents once a thread has begun its process.

As far as I'm aware, the only MongoDB operator that could be used is [`$isolated`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/isolated/index.html) but I'm not sure it can be achieved even with this.

Is there any other way? And if not, any input on whether $isolated will work with this kind of use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [findOneAndDelete](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete) and [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify) (with `remove: true`) are atomic on document level.

$isolated applies only to write operations. It won't help *to ensure that other application threads will never **read***.

For multi-document transaction you will need to implement it on application level using optimistic locks. See [2 phase commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/index.html) for inspiration.